# Regular expression to find matches anywhere separately

Tags: regex, dart

How do I write a regular expression to match two given strings separately?

```
final template = r'''
  must not be captured

    @template(*Map<String, Function> _deserializer;
    Map<String, Function> get deserializer => _deserializer ??= <String, Function>{
      @map(* ~id:#deserializer# ~template: #r'~key': ~value,# *)
    };*)


    must not be captured

    @template(*List<String> _myList;
    List<String> get myList => _myList ??= <String>[
      @list(* ~id:#myList# ~template: #~value,# *)
    ];*)

     must not be captured

''';


const String template = r'@template\s*\(\*[\w\W]+\*\)';
```

In general. I want each of the string parts that starts with the "@template(*" and ends with the "*)"  to be found separately, not together.

Comment: I removed my answer as I missed that you needed a solution for Dart. In Python, the following pattern works for your problem, when used with the `.findall()` method of the `re` library and using the `re.DOTALL` argument so `.` matches across linebreaks: `(\@template.+?;\*\))`
I don't know the Dart language, so I don't know if the above will translate neatly into Dart code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Regex that @MurrayW suggested in this way:

```
final regex = RegExp(r'(\@template.+?;\*\))', dotAll: true);


void main() {
  var matches = regex.allMatches(template);

 for (var match in matches) {
   print(match.group(1));
 }
}
```

Using your template as input the result will be:

```
@template(*Map<String, Function> _deserializer;
    Map<String, Function> get deserializer => _deserializer ??= <String, Function>{
      @map(* ~id:#deserializer# ~template: #r'~key': ~value,# *)
    };*)

@template(*List<String> _myList;
    List<String> get myList => _myList ??= <String>[
      @list(* ~id:#myList# ~template: #~value,# *)
    ];*)
```

Comment: Hi, where is this "dotAll: true" ??? I'm using dart as I mentioned before

Comment: i found thath:   @Since("2.4") bool dotAll: false

Comment: Try updating your dart version at least 2.4 then